# Multiple arguments causing Discord bot to run out of memory?

Tags: node.js, discord.io

I created a Discord bot to roll die when you say 'roll 1d6' or 'roll 1d6 1d20' etc, but if I give it more than one argument it causes the script to freeze and then run out of memory.

I'm not that great at NodeJS so I'm not sure what's going on here.

https://pastebin.com/vVxuvVNw

I think it's something to do with the second loop,

```
for (i = 1; i < args.length; i++) {
    if(args[i].includes('d')) {
        var dice = args[i].split('d');
        for (i = 0; i < dice[0]; i++) {
            diemsg += getRandomInt(dice[1]) + ' ';
        }
        diemsg += '`\n';
    }
}
```

But I couldn't figure it out myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re usin the same variable I in the inner loop, which overwrites the i in the outer loop.

Comment: Thank you!! I don't know how this went over my head, but it did work!